# Trying to build react native app for Android on Mac M1 - Error: No emulators found as an output of `emulator -list-avds`

Tags: android, react-native, android-emulator

I have installed Android Studio on my mac M1
I have added a virtual device in Android Studio using Device Manager
The app builds fine from inside Android Studio......however when I run `npx react-native run-android` from command line in VSCode, I get the error `No emulators found as an output of emulator -list-avds`
However when I navigate to emulator folder using `cd ~/Library/Android/sdk/emulator` and run command `./emulator -avd {AVD_NAME}`, the emulator starts fine.....however even with the emulator running, the command `npx react-native run-android` still gives the error `No emulators found as an output of emulator -list-avds`

**UPDATE 04/26** - I followed instructions from @qqNade, however I am still getting same error...see screenshot below:
[image]

Just noticed from the screenshot above, the error

```
/bin/sh: adb: command not found
```

..also, when I run `echo $PATH` in terminal, I get the following response:
`/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin`

I dont see any reference to android in there, so I assume thats not a good thing

**UPDATE 04/26 #2**
I added a `~/.zshrc` file and populated it as per below:

```
export ANDROID_HOME="$HOME/Library/Android/sdk"
export 
PATH="$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$PATH"
```

..that solved the `/bin/sh: adb: command not found` error, but now I have a new one:

```
error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: spawn ./gradlew EACCES
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:283:19)
    at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:476:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
```

....at least its launching the emulator now

**UPDATE 04/26 #3**
A number of SO posts told me to run the following command from android folder (and then clean)

```
chmod +x gradlew;
```

...now Im getting a different error:

```
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
./gradlew: line 188: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Im wondering if this has anything to do with fact that I created the app originally on Windows.....and this is the first time Im trying to build on Mac?
I checked gradlew file in VSCode and its showing as LF (not CRLF) which as I understand it is correct when building for Mac

Answer (score 2):

I also faced such a problem, to solve it you need to open a command prompt and enter

```
nano ~/.zsh_profile
```

after which you need to add this to the file and save

```
export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/emulator
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

then enter on the command line

```
source $HOME/.zsh_profile
```

Comment: As per original post - unfortunately this proposed solution did not work

Answer (score 0):

I want to help you.

You're in the home directory (you can go there with cd $HOME or cd ~)

```
export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/emulator
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools

source ~/.bash_profile (or source ~/.zshrc, take a look at my note at the end please)
```

After that, when you execute command vi .bash_profile (or vi .zshrc), you should see something like that

[image]

At this point, you can try to execute emulator -list-avds command again

And yes, echo $PATH should show you entries related with Android like ~/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools

echo $ANDROID_HOME as well

If still not working, I would try to navigate to android folder and run the commands below one more time

```
chmod +x gradlew
./gradlew clean
react-native run-android
```

NOTE: Please be sure which shell your mac is using with the command below.

```
echo $0
```

Further reading

[setting up development environment](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup)

Comment: How does this differ from [the answer posted on 26 April](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72015131), where the OP responded with *As per original post - unfortunately this proposed solution did not work*.

Comment: One difference is clearly seen that I have given a command to be sure which shell his Mac is using to determine which file he needs to change. I have also given an alternative solution with one extra command. Furthermore, I have shared a link because he may be overlooked something.

Comment: As per my inital post, I fixed the orignal issue by updating my ~/.zshrc file.  The issue I now have remaining is Error: `Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
./gradlew: line 188: syntax error: unexpected end of file `

Answer (score 0):

I have used homebrew for setting up

echo $PATH

/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Users/userName/Library/Android/sdk/emulator:/Users/userName/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools

when we get this error,

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: spawn ./gradlew EACCES
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:283:19)
at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:476:16)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)

try running this command and it will update the gradlew file with access permission, this is for M1 chip machine only

cd android

chmod +x gradlew

This solved my issue

Comment: fresh setup of react native environment on M1 chip use homebrew